# using await inside another await

Tags: c#, async-await

I am developing a web api and I have some async methods from EF. All the examples I read on the internet show simple calls or snipets, but not what I am looking for...so, this is my question:

I have this method in my repository class:

```
public async Task GuardarLibro(Book book)
{
    var dbLibro = _libroConverter.Convert(libro);

    using (_migraPleContext)
    {
        _migraPleContext.Libro.Add(dbLibro);
        await _migraPleContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Then I have another class that calls my repository...since, the method from my repository is async, I call it this way:

```
var libroDb = _libroConverter.Convert(libro);
await _libroRepository.GuardarLibro(libroDb);
```

My question is, if this approach is correct. I am using an await in my handler class and another await in my repository class, and I am not sure if this is a good practice or if it has a performance impact.

Comment: I don't see the link between the two snippets. Is `GuardarLibro` translated to `SaveBook`?

Comment: Hi Rob, yes, It was my bad, I should have used GuardarLibro from the start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one correct way in which `async/await` can be used.

You may consider also calling [`.ConfigureAwait(false);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) on each awaitable `Task` if you do not require the context to captured.

Comment: Thanks Russ for your feedback. Does ConfigureAwait makes an improvement in performance?

Comment: @trololog85 yes, performance _should_ also be slightly better using `ConfigureAwait(false)`